# Python - network buffer handling question

Tags: python, networking, struct

I want to design a game server in python. The game will mostly just be passing small packets filled with ints, strings, and bytes stuffed into one message. As I'm using a different language to write the game, a normal packet would be sent like so:

```
Writebyte(buffer, 5); // Delimit type of message
Writestring(buffer, "Hello");
Sendmessage(buffer, socket);
```

As you can see, it writes the bytes to the buffer, and sends the buffer. Is there any way to read something like this in python? I am aware of the struct module, and I've used it to pack things, but I've never used it to actually read something with mixed types stuck into one message. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). Protocol Buffers gives you a multi-language, fast, extensible message serialization framework. You can easily add fields later, parse messages in most popular languages, and embed message types within other message types. It will save you a lot of time as compared to coding your own serialization framework.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://twistedmatrix.com/ and http://construct.wikispaces.com/